# Spring Boot Application cannot boot up after changing JBoss standalone.xml

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, https, jboss

My Spring Boot Application cannot boot up in JBoss after I remove below line from Jboss config file standalone.xml for security reasons.

`<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>`

However, the application failed to boot up after the removal. 
Here is the error extracted from server.log

```
2019-01-15 10:48:55,167 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "customerdata.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
"Services that were unable to start:" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ArgumentTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.HtmlEscapeTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.NestedPathTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ParamTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.ThemeTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.TransformTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ButtonTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxesTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.RadioButtonsTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.TextareaTag\".START",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".deploymentCompleteService",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"customerdata.war\".ejb3.client-context.registration-service",
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./customerdata",
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./customerdata.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"
],
"Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
```

}}

Is there a way to boot up Spring Boot App in JBoss without **"jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"**?